# SCLAlertView Library - How to trigger it from another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working with this alert library SCLAlertView. Ib my app I have a left menu. When the users is offline and they are trying to click on a menu item, I want to trigger and alert.

But since the menu controller is underneath the main controller in the hierarchy, the alert is shown underneath the main view. Is there a way to send it to the top of the hierarchy so it will display on top of the main controller?

Menu.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (![Utilities checkConnection]) {
        // hides the menu
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopView]; 

        // Display alert
        SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];
        LNViewController *ln = [[LNViewController alloc] init]; // main view controller

        [alert showError:ln title:@"Connection Error"
                subTitle:@"Looks like you lost connection. Please connect to the internet and refresh the view."
        closeButtonTitle:@"OK" duration:0.0f];
    } else {            
        Dep *dep = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.delegate menuViewControllerDelegate:self selectDep:dep];

        // Deselect the row
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the self (MenuViewController) to the showError method, if the parent of the MenuViewController is the MainViewController, pass self.parentViewController instead of self. That should make the alert appear over your MainViewController.

Change your code for displaying the error to the following:

```
[alert showError:self.parentViewController title:@"Connection Error"
        subTitle:@"Looks like you lost connection. Please connect to the internet and refresh the view."
closeButtonTitle:@"OK" duration:0.0f];
```

Initializing a MainViewController object does not automatically link or "point" to the active MainViewController object in your view controller hierarchy.

Comment: Oh wait  I got it. Let me try it

Comment: Plzz look at the code again I made a change to it, but still doesnt work.